# ¿Cómo hacer una celda en la que se guarda la fecha de modificación de un rango concreto de celdas?

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy intentando crear una celda que me guarde automáticamente la fecha de modificación de un rango de celdas en concreto. No se cual será la mejor forma de hacerlo, pero creo que con un script sería algo como esto:

```
function onEdit(e){
 var DateCol = "K8";
 var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC+1", "hh:mm")
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
 var range = sheet.getRange('C11:K18');
 //range.activate();
 var rowIndex = range.getRowIndex();
 var colIndex = range.getColumnIndex();

 // May need to set up multiple ranges like this and check all ranges if
 // checked fields are not in adjacent cells
 var watchRange = { // B2:G20
   top : 11,         // start row
   bottom : 18,     // end row
   left : 3,        // start col
   right : 11,        // end col
 };
 // Exit if we're out of range
 if (rowIndex < watchRange.top || rowIndex > watchRange.bottom) return;
 if (colIndex < watchRange.left || colIndex > watchRange.right) return;

 var currentValue = range.getValue();
 currentValue = currentValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,""); //"trim" kludge

 if (currentValue.length == 0){

 // Set a column to show last edit date
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(DateCol + rowIndex).setValue("Edited: " + 
 curDate);

 }
}
```

Ahora mismo no me da un error de ejecución, pero no me escribe la fecha en la celda y me selecciona el rango de todas las hojas y no de una en concreto.

He conseguido que no me seleccione todas las hojas modificando la línea 4

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Test2');
```

He modificado la línea 26

```
if (currentValue.length != 0)
```

Modificando la línea 29 me escribe en la celda que quiero

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(DateCol).setValue(curDate);
```

Lo único que me falla es que me pone 1h de menos haga lo que haga.

He modificado esto y se ha solucionado

```
var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+01:00", "hh:mm");
```

Comment: No es correcto modificar una pregunta para introducir otra pregunta y menos aún si has recibido una respuesta que te ha sido útil. Sólo en el caso de que la respuesta no haya solucionado el problema tendría sentido modificar la pregunta para dar información adicional para que los respondedores puedan hacer respuestas que efectivamente solucionen el problema.

Comment: En este caso es claro que la edición debería publicarse como una pregunta, pues hasta la redacción menciona que se trata de "el siguiente paso". Lo más apropiado sería que publicaras una nueva pregunta y en esta revertir a la revisión 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Lo único que me falla es que me pone 1h de menos haga lo que haga.

Lo más probable es que esto se deba a que tu hoja de cálculo tiene una zona horaria distinta a la indicada en

```
var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC+1", "hh:mm")
```

En [Configurar la ubicación regional y los ajustes de cálculo de una hoja de cálculo](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?hl=es) se explica como consultar/modificar la zona horaria de tu hoja de cálculo.

Comment: El tema de la franja esta solucionado, la hoja de calculo utiliza su propio formato de date.